# how to change css of my GWT TabPanel

Tags: gwt

I am trying to change my css for the tab panel 
here is my code

```
      <g:HTMLPanel>
    <div class="center">
        <g:TabLayoutPanel ui:field="tabPanel" barUnit="PX"
            barHeight="60" width="500px" height="250px" 
                                 styleName="gwt-TabPanel">
            <g:tab >
                <g:header>
                    DashBoard
        </g:header>
```

I have this css

```
    .gwt-TabPanel {
    background-color: rgb(36, 36, 36);
    }

    .roundedTab {
    background-color: red;  
    }

   .gwt-TabBar {
    background-color: rgb(36, 36, 36);
    padding-top: 5px;
    }

    .gwt-TabPanelBottom {
    background-color: rgb(64, 64, 64);
    border-top: none;

    padding-top: 1px;
    margin: 0px 0px 3px 0px;
    }

    .gwt-TabBar .gwt-TabBarFirst {
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(36, 36, 36);
    padding-left: 3px;
    }

   .gwt-TabBar .gwt-TabBarRest {
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(36, 36, 36);
    padding-right: 3px;
    }

   .gwt-TabBar .gwt-TabBarItem {           
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(36, 36, 36);

    margin-left: 2px;
    margin-right: 2px;

    cursor: pointer;
    cursor: hand;

    background-color: rgb(48, 48, 48);
    } 

    .gwt-TabBar .gwt-TabBarItem-selected {  
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(64, 64, 64);       
    background-color: rgb(64, 64, 64);
    }

    .gwt-TabBar .selectedText {
    color: white;
    background-color: rgb(64, 64, 64);
    font-weight: bold;      
    padding: 3px 7px 5px 7px;
    }

    .gwt-TabBar .unselectedText {
    color: rgb(227, 209, 13);       
    background-color: rgb(48, 48, 48);

    padding: 3px 7px 5px 7px;       
    }

   .gwt-TabBar .onMouseEnter {
    color: white;
    background-color: rgb(64, 64, 64);
    }

    .gwt-TabBar .onMouseLeave {

     }

    .deckPanel {
    margin: 5px;
   }
```

[image]

But it make the whole tab panel black and the Tabs also disappear .
What i want is to make every tab (not the complete tab Panel) background-color to blue and remove the border of the tabPanel

Any idea how can i achieve this.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the background-color property from  .gwt-TabPanel and add new CSS property as,

```
.gwt-TabLayoutPanelTab {
    background-color: blue;
}
```

.gwt-TabPanel is the CSS for whole Tabpanel but .gwt-TabLayoutPanelTab is the CSS applied for each tab.

Comment: And if you want to remove the border of content container which holds the data in each tab then, use CSS, .gwt-TabLayoutPanelContentContainer{
 border: none !important;
}

Comment: thanks , i just add that .gwt-TabLayoutPanelTab {
    background-color: blue;
}  , It makes the tabs Blue , But it removes the tab Style , Please see the attached image above , thanks

Comment: Remove the styleName="gwt-TabPanel" from your ui.xml file. And also, i confirm that you have <inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.theme.clean.Clean'/> in your .gwt.xml file.

Comment: ur both things working , but by using !important  in both ,thanks +1 . Now the header at the top in gray color ,i want to remove this header or make its color to white ,how can i achieve this(see the attached image). Thanks

Comment: which header? Task Management? Or override services?

Comment: No ,where these 3 tabs are located, DashBoard,Client,Reports , back to these 3 , u can see gray color , i dont want that gray color

Comment: Do this, .gwt-TabLayoutPanel .gwt-TabLayoutPanelTabs {background: none !important;}